# Extra data when writing to the console after pulling data from file

Tags: c#

I have a file with values separated by commas which I load into a string array using this code.

```
string test = File.ReadAllText(path).Split(',');
```

If I print that array using a for loop something like

```
for(i=0;i<93;i++;)
{
    Console.WriteLine(test[i]);
}
```

The output prints 93 items and if I make i<94 then 95 items print. Please explain what's going on and how to only print out 94 items.

Comment: It might be because of unicode characters, where some signs are stored as two bytes and not one, but represented visually by one character

Comment: A loop with 94 iterations doesn't print 95 items. I think that you have a line break in the 94th item so that it looks like two items.

Comment: @user853710: He's never treating the data like an array of bytes, so that will not be the case.

Comment: For a CSV file, it might be clearer to `ReadAllLines` then `.Split` each. Also, did you check if there were that many items? Also this won't compile since you can't assign a `String[]` to a `String`.

Comment: You could do `var values = File.ReadAllLines(path).SelectMany(line=>line.Split(','))` To get all the values separated by line and comma.

Comment: true, .true. maybe \r\n character. try, using readalllines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still writing out 94 items, it's just that the 94th item has a newline in it, so it will result in 95 lines written.  So a file that looks like

> 1,2,3
>
> 4,5,6

Would result in an array with the values 1, 2, 3\n4, 5 and 6 for your code. Where \n is the newline.  Printing out the 3rd value will result in 2 lines instead of one thus making it seem like a total of 6 items, when you actually only have 5.

If you want to separate at the lines you can do the following

```
var values = File.ReadLines(path).SelectMany(line=>line.Split(','));
```

Which will separate the 3 and 4 into separate items for the above example and if you loop to the 3rd item you'd only get 3 instead of 3\n4.  Additionally by using `ReadLines` versus `ReadAllLines` or `ReadAllText` you won't load the entire file into memory at once.  It will instead read one line at a time, split it and then read the next as you iterate the resulting `IEnumerable<string>`.  Not a big deal for small files, but can save you from running out of memory with large ones.

Answer (score 0):

You should not hard code a number.  93, 94, whatever.

```
    string[] words = File.ReadAllText(path).Split(',');

    foreach (string s in words)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

OR (less preferred)

```
    string[] words = File.ReadAllText(path).Split(',');

    for(i=0;i<words.Length;i++;)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test[i]);
    }
```

I would avoid this all together.

You can google "C# CVS" and find lots of third party helpers.

Or you can use this ".Net" (with a VB.NET assembly) (Note, you have to reference Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll )

from

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

```
using (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser MyReader = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("c:\\logs\\bigfile")) {

MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited;
MyReader.Delimiters = new string[] { Constants.vbTab };
string[] currentRow = null;
//Loop through all of the fields in the file. 
//If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing. 
while (!MyReader.EndOfData) {
    try {
        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields();
        // Include code here to handle the row.
    } catch (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException ex) {
        Interaction.MsgBox("Line " + ex.Message + " is invalid.  Skipping");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't want to print all the items in the array just some of them

Comment: @Timothy this is enough to get you started .. if you want to print some of the items then you need to add some `if(){}` conditional for items you want to skip.. please show some effort

Comment: Then inside the "foreach" do a check against the data.  Your question needs more details.  Also, if you're parsing a CSV file, there are better ways to shred the data.

Comment: This still doesn't touch on the root of the OP's issue that they see 95 lines because the 94th item has a newline.  The fix is to also split on newlines as well as commas.

Comment: It's a lack of understanding not effort. For future reference how can I use foreach to only print a specific section of the array?

Comment: @Timothy If you want to print the first n items then you can use `foreach` and `Take`.  like `foreach(var n in list.Take(7))`.  The nice thing about `Take` is that it will also stop  if the list has fewer than 7 items.

Comment: You need to add sample lines of data and expected results to your original questions.  We cannot read your mind on what is "good" and "ignore" data.

Comment: can I use Take to grab something in the middle?

Comment: Skip and Take are LINQ operators.

Comment: thanks for helping this newb